# Jersey hello world gives 404

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey

I have the following code in my java class

```
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {
    //This method is called is TEXT_PLAIN is request
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayPlainTextHello(){
        return "Hello World";
    }

    //this method is called if TEXT_XML is requested
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String sayXMLHello(){
        return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>"+"<Hello> Hello World"+"</hello>";
    }

    //this method is called if HTML is requested
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String sayHtmlHello(){
        return "<html>"+"<title>"+"hello jersey"+"</title>"+"<body><h1>"+"hello World!!"+"</body></h1>"+"</html>";
    }
}
```

I compiled it and exported it as a .WAR file , when I type

> http://127.0.0.1/test_server/hello

I get a 404 . I tried it in WTP, cURL they all return 404.. I'm using tomcat 7.0.26

Note: I am running Tomcat on port 80, and other servlets respond as expected.

**web.xml config**

```
<display-name>Jersey_Test</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example.service</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

The following URL gives me Http status 500

```
 http://localhost/Jersey_Test/rest/hello
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
```

Comment: the web.xml is the same as the first answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been fixed and this is how I did it.

I removed the jersey .jar files from the build path and replaced them in the `WEB-INF\lib` folder and everything worked.

Answer (score 9):

That can happen if you haven't registered the JAX-RS servlet implementation in your `web.xml` at all. Jersey requires the following configuration:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example.service</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The `com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages` initialization parameter value must point to the package where all your services are. Your code snippet is however missing the `package` declaration. I'm not sure if this is omitted for brevity or not, but packageless classes are invisible to classes which are by itself in a package (such as the Tomcat and Jersey engines itself). The above `web.xml` example assumes that you've a

```
package com.example.service;
```

on your webservice classes. Fix or change it accordingly.

Note that the URL-pattern of `/*` thus means that ALL requests will be passed through Jersey. If you need to deploy other servlets, JSP or static content in the same webapp as well, you might want to specify a more specific URL pattern. E.g.

```xml
<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
```

You'll only need to change your request URL to http://localhost/test_server/rest/hello.

Comment: I'm getting the following error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer` I have the following .jar files in my buildpath `asm-3.1.jar, jersey-core-1.12.jar, jersey-server-1.12.jar, jersey servlet-1.12.jar and jsr311-api-1.11.jar` one more question regarding `web.xml` I've been using a book to learn servlet programming , its a new one written by budi kurniawan. I haven't come across editing web.xml so far in the book , I used to write them and then export it as a `.war` file and it worked , so I'm kinda confused now with the purpose of web.xml.

Comment: Updated question with current `web.xml` config

Comment: Which servletcontainer are you deploying to?

Comment: I'm deploying this on a tomcat server

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are registering your servlet in the wrong place. Double check that the root URL of your servlet, and make sure that matches what you are hitting.

Have you tried hitting?:

```
http://127.0.0.1/hello
```

Remember that `/hello` will go after whatever the base URL of your servlet is. Try looking a it in a debugger to see where it mounts.

Answer (score 0):

For me, there was a `jar` file added in `Build path -> Libraries` for which the actual `jar` was missing from the file system.

I removed the entry from `build path` and added the dependency in `pom.xml`. 
worked like a charm.